# Zooming into cursor in GraphicsView/GraphicsScene

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, zooming, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsView` widget which I'm using as a drawing canvas.

I want to be able to zoom into the mouse cursor position on `ctrl+mwheel`. As my code stands, it is scrolling only it seems into the center of the canvas, and not into the cursor position. It seems that the translation logic is wrong but I don't see how:

```
def zoomCanvas(self, event):
    zoomInFactor = 1.25
    zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor
    oldPos = event.scenePos()
    if event.delta() > 0:
        zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
    else:
        zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
    self.graphicsView.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)
    newPos = event.scenePos()
    delta = newPos - oldPos
    self.graphicsView.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo

Add these 2 to graphicsView init

```
    self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
    self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
```